# Vuetify instance with cdn not work on vuejs3

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, cdn

I have application on aspnet mvc and import vuejs v3 cdn and i like use vuetify but i dont know how do it.
its my code example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - MVCAndVue</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
<script>
const {
    ref,
    reactive,
} = Vue;
//Define Vue app
const App = {
    data() {
        return {
        };
    },
    methods: {
        
    },
    setup(props, context) {
        
    }
};
// Create new Vue app
const app = Vue.createApp(App);
app.mount("#app");

</script>
```

Comment: This is how you can do it: https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#cdn Meanwhile, avoiding using a CDN if possible. Use an NPM package, will be faster, safer, easier and following the conventions.

Comment: Also see this related question for Vuetify: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77557516/8583692

Answer (score 7):

You are facing this issue because you included **Vuetify 2.x** which is not compatible with Vue 3. So, use [Vuetify 3](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/) instead.

Now, the right way to use Vuetify via CDNs, you need to follow these steps-

1. Import Vuetify CSS in your `head` tag-

```html
<link
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.0.5/dist/vuetify.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
```

2. If you want to use material design icons, then import this CSS link in your `head` tag too-

```html
<link
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
```

3. Import the Vuetify script in your `body` tag-

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.0.5/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

4. If you are planning to use Vue3 also via CDN, then import the Vue script in your `body` tag-

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

Here is a complete working HTML file with all necessary imported CDNs for Vue3 and Vuetify3-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <link
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet"
    />
  <link
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.0.5/dist/vuetify.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet"
    />
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.0.5/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/x-template" id="app-template">
      <v-app>
        <v-card
          class="mx-auto"
          width="400"
          append-icon="mdi-human-greeting"
        >
          <template v-slot:title>
            Title
          </template>
          <v-card-text>
            Description
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-app>
    </script>
    <script>
      const { createApp } = Vue;
      const { createVuetify } = Vuetify;
      
      const vuetify = createVuetify();
      
      const app = createApp({
        template: "#app-template", 
      })
        .use(vuetify)
        .mount("#app");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

To read more about using CDNs, read here-

1. https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#cdn
2. https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/#material-design-icons

Comment: Nice, It should be nice to have in Getting started. Sometimes you need this setup

Comment: Yes, sometimes we need this full setup while testing something. @JohanHoeksma